# How to enable Agent Channel Type on Asterisk 13

Tags: asterisk

I'm using Asterisk 13 and building a PBX application controller to Call Centers. I'm facing a issue when handling agents, for some reason, Asterisk 13 doesnt have the channel type Agent enabled by default, so I don't know how to do to add an Agent on a queue member.

```
[May 17 02:03:58] WARNING[1767][C-00000001]: channel.c:5932 ast_request: No channel type registered for 'Agent'
```

There is anyway to enable Channel Type Agent on Asterisk 13? The member i'm testing is configured like that on queue.conf:

```
member => Agent/marcioantonio,0,Márcio Antônio,Agent:marcioantonio,no
```

And to login I just use the following AMI:

```
Action: Originate
Channel: Local/2000@login-agent
Application: AgentLogin
Data: marcioantonio,s
CallerID: OdinPBX Login Agent
Variable: login=marcioantonio
```

Note: The Variable is just for logging prupose. And here is the Dialplan of login-agent context:

```
[login-agent]

exten => _[0-9a-zA-Z].,1,NoOp(Trying to log agent ${login} on ${EXTEN})
same => n,Dial(Local/${EXTEN}@extensions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, I found a way without Channel Type Agent. The trick is to use `AgentRequest(AgentId)` function on dialplan. So after changing my dialplan to:

```
[login-agent]

exten => _[0-9a-zA-Z].,1,NoOp(Trying to log agent ${login} on ${EXTEN})
same => n,Dial(Local/${EXTEN}@extensions)

[agents]

exten => _[0-9a-zA-Z].,1,NoOp(Connecting the current call to agent ${EXTEN})
same => n,AgentRequest(${EXTEN})
same => n,Hangup()
```

And the member on queue.conf:

```
member => Local/marcioantonio@agents,0,Márcio Antônio,Agent:marcioantonio,no
```

The queue and agents are working fine!

```
Márcio Antônio (Local/marcioantonio@agents from Agent:marcioantonio) (ringinuse disabled) (Not in use) has taken 5 calls (last was 346 secs ago)
```

Hope this help someone else!